# Introducing CrossValidated.SE Pizza Ambassadors Program: calling students and teachers

Tags: discussion

StackExchange is looking for students and teachers who might be interested in helping us kick off/formalize a pizza ambassador-type program. CrossValidated.StackExchange would like to sponsor university students (college or graduate) and faculty members who are excited about CrossValidated, statistics and pizza. Contact Seth Rogers for more details about the program and to get involved.

Comment: I've never objected to good food, and am fond of CV. What's the best way to get ahold of you?

Comment: The best way to contact me is via email, seth@stackexchange.com (also on my user profile page).

Comment: @Seth your email probably isn't visible to non-mods or high-rep users - it is invisible by default. Maybe put it in your bio field (like in mine).

Comment: Will you illustrate who gets the slices of pizza with a pie chart?  Bad stats joke.  :) (And a "bad stats" joke.)